# How to destroy named jquery-styles at once via click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do apply some styles to my layout (several elements) via jquery and want to "delete" these styles after clicking another button. This is add the styles:

```
$("#trigger_menu").click(function () {
    $(".sw_2-emotionen").css({
        "padding": "15% 2vw",
        "width": "25%"
    });
    $(".sw_2-technik").css({
        "padding": "15% 2vw",
        "width": "25%"
    });
    $(".sw_1-logo").css({
        "padding-left": "0%",
        "width": "50%"
    });
    $(".sw_3-bordershake").css("width", "45.84vw");
    $(".hidden_nav").slideToggle("slow", function () {
    });
    location.hash = "#menu_on";
});
```

And this is how I'd like to remove those again; but this doesn't do anything (besides correctly toggling the .hidden_nav element, which means the command "removeAttr" doesn't work as intended:

```
$("#trigger_menu2").click(function () {
    $(".sw_2-emotionen", ".sw_2-technik", ".sw_1-logo", ".sw_3-bordershake").removeAttr("style");
    $(".hidden_nav").slideToggle("slow", function () {
    });
    location.hash = "#menu_off";
});
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Simple answer, don't put the style information in JS. Use classes. Then you can simply `addClass()`/`removeClass()`, or even just `toggleClass()`, as needed

Comment: Agree with @RoryMcCrossan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, don't put the style information in JS. Use classes. Then you can simply `addClass()`/`removeClass()`, or even just `toggleClass()`, as needed.

Also note that when selecting multiple elements you should use a single string with each selector separated by a comma, and that you don't *have* to provide a callback function to `slideToggle()` if you don't need to use one. Try this:

```css
.sw_1-logo.active {
    padding: 0%;
    width: 50%;
}
.sw_2-emotionen.active {
    padding: 15% 2vw;
    width: 25%;
} 
.sw_2-technik.active {
    padding: 15% 2vw;
    width: 25%;
}
.sw_3-bordershake.active {
    width: 45.84vw;
}
```

```js
$("#trigger_menu").click(function() {
    $(".sw_1-logo, .sw_2-emotionen, .sw_2-technik, .sw_3-bordershake").addClass('active');
    $(".hidden_nav").slideToggle("slow")
    location.hash = "#menu_on";
});

$("#trigger_menu2").click(function () {
    $(".sw_1-logo, .sw_2-emotionen, .sw_2-technik, .sw_3-bordershake").removeClass('active');
    $(".hidden_nav").slideToggle("slow")
    location.hash = "#menu_off";
});
```

Comment: That was more then I expected!

Answer (score 0):

An empty string deletes the properties. For instances:

```
$(".sw_2-emotionen, .sw_2-technik, .sw_1-logo").css({
    "padding": "",
    "width": ""
});
```

Answer (score 0):

RemoveAttr work if you set style attr in tag only .. and doesn't work to remove all style in the head tag